# Clone not implemented on function... sometimes

Tags: rust

I have a vector of functiony enums. I want to clone this vector en masse. However, my Action enum can't derive Clone because Clone isn't implemented for a

```
fn(&mut Vec<i32>)
```

It works if it's

```
fn(Vec<i32>)
```

though. It doesn't seem to like fns that borrow their parameters. Why is this? Is there a way for me to do this?

```
#[derive(Clone)]
enum Action {
    Function (fn(&mut Vec<i32>))
}
fn pop(vec:&mut Vec<i32>) {
    let _ = vec.pop();
}
fn main() {
    let actions = vec![ Action::Function(pop), Action::Function(pop) ];
    let actions_copy = actions.to_vec();
}
```

Comment: 2017: See https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28229, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/43690.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation of `Clone` for `fn`s [isn't complete](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/clone.rs.html#92), so this isn't possible as-is, though it's intended to be fixed at some point.

In the meantime one thing you can do, albeit at the cost of an extra indirection, is to put it inside something like an `Rc` or `Arc`, since that is indeed `Clone`.

See this example which assumes you want thread-safety, hence the `Arc`, though a simple `Rc` may suffice in your case:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Action {
    Function (Arc<fn(&mut Vec<i32>)>)
}
fn pop(vec:&mut Vec<i32>) {
    let _ = vec.pop();
}
fn main() {
    let actions = vec![ Action::Function(Arc::new(pop)), Action::Function(Arc::new(pop)) ];
    let actions_copy = actions.to_vec();
}
```

[playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bdb1e081501bdb9faac6&version=stable)